# Graph of a $C^k$ function is $C^k$ manifold

Tags: proof-verification, smooth-manifolds

I got a problem

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^k$ function between two Euclidean spaces. And let a set $A$ be a graph of $f$.
Show that $A$ is a $C^k$ manifold.

And I solved it.

Could you check if it’s right?

I think it must be wrong, because, in my proof, I didn’t use the condition that $f$ is $C^k$.

Step 1

I showed there is a homeomorphism from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I used the following map,
$\varphi: \mathbb{R}^m \to A$ defined by 
$$\varphi(x_1,...,x_m)=(x_1,...,x_m,f(x_1,...x_m)).$$

It is a bijective map since $f$ is a function.
Also we can show that it is continuous.(By using inverse image of open set is open)

And its inverse map is also continuous(just by using the composite an inclusion map and a projection map)

Step 2

Thus $(A,\varphi^{-1})$ is a global chart and thus consists of an atlas. So it can be extended to a maximal atlas.

So, the graph of $f$ is manifold. Actually, it is a smooth manifold. Thus it is $C^k$ manifold.

///

I don’t know where I should use $C^k$ condition here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a subtlety in this situation that might not be obvious at first. What you proved (correctly) is that the graph is a topological manifold, and that it has a smooth structure. That's true as long as $f$ is merely continuous.

Sometimes, though, when people ask whether a certain subset of Euclidean space is a $C^k$ manifold, what they really have in mind is whether it is a **$\boldsymbol C^k$ submanifold**. To show that, you'd need $f$ to be at least of class $C^k$.

Comment: In my book, submanifold didn’t appear yet! Then what the author means is not submanifold.  Thank you!

Comment: By the way, it sounds weird that it is smooth manifold but not smooth submanifold.. Haha

Comment: Is it like the real line is an open set in itself but not open in the coordinate space?

Comment: @anadad: Sort of like that. Here's another useful analogy: We can put a topology on the $x$-axis that makes it a discrete space (every point is an open set), but that's not the topology it inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Ohhh I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The differentiable structure induced by a single global chart is always smooth, given that the change of charts is trivially the identity map.

It's only required continuity of $f$ is order to give continuity of $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you! As long as f is continuous, the result of the problem is unchanged? And my proof works fine?